# Comparar un string

Tags: java

¿Como puedo saber si un String es superior a otro en java?

El codigo:

Estuve buscando pero solo me hablan sobre el metodo equals y el metodo compareTo

```
  String nom1="",nom2="";

  Scanner leer=new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.print("Escriba los nombres");
  System.out.println();

  System.out.print("Primer nombre: ");
  nom1=leer.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Segundo nombre: ");
  nom2=leer.nextLine();

  if(nom1.compareTo(nom2)){

     System.out.println(nom1);    
     System.out.print(nom2);

  }else{

     System.out.print(nom2);
     System.out.print(nom1);
  }
```

Comment: Define *superior* en el contexto de la comparación que deseas.

Comment: _superior_ en qué sentido? cadena más larga? peso en bytes? mayúsculas o minúsculas? se torna a interpretación

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que .comparteTo devuelve un número, es decir, devuelve 0 si las cadenas son iguales, -1 si la primera es menor y 1 si es mayor.

```
if(nom1.compareTo(nom2) < 0){ //Así quedaría si la cadena 1 es mayor que la cadena 2

     System.out.println(nom1);    
     System.out.print(nom2);

  }else{ // Aquí arrojaría la cadena 2, puesto que ésta sería la mayor.

     System.out.print(nom2);
     System.out.print(nom1);
  }
```

En base a lo que te escribí arriba y al ejemplo, puedes realizar lo que desees.

Más información [aquí.](https://programandoointentandolo.com/2013/10/como-comparar-string-en-java.html#:%7E:text=Otra%20alternativa%20para%20comparar%20cadenas,y%201%20si%20es%20mayor.)